# How to make a shield.io badge with just a logo in the left side?

Tags: request, badge

Following [Shield.io](https://shields.io/) instructions, We can use the `logo` param to access a bunch of icons available through [Simple Icons](https://simpleicons.org/) index. However I couldn't use them in the badge left side without determine a label too.

The badge [image: Example] is produced as result of the following request:

```
https://img.shields.io/static/v1?logo=react&message=React&color=Blue
```

Is possible to get just an icon in the left side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally use '%20' as label, which is the space character encoded using Percent-encoding (see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

For your badge the correct url would be :

```
https://img.shields.io/static/v1?message=React&logo=react&labelColor=5c5c5c&color=1182c3&logoColor=white&label=%20
```